# Drupal Zen theme without compass

Tags: drupal, themes

I would like to know it's possible to work with zen theme without using Compass?
Instead of using Compass i was thinking to use Gulp to compile Sass files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Zen 7.x-6.x-dev branch is using Gulp, Node.js and KSS to compile SASS. As of mid-2015, it appears that gulp still uses compass to compile the CSS. So, you would have to put in some effort to get it to work with an alternate compiler, including reorganizing the package.json and gulp.js  files.

Jon Albin says in an April, 2015 comment that he is watching developments in Libsass.

Zen 7.x-6.x-dev is already a huge improvement when it comes to SMACSS, but it is undergoing a lot of development to correspond to Drupal 8 practices. I expect that Zen theme will lose its dependence on Compass at some point in that process.